# Editing the file input tag so it will look a certain way

Tags: css

I have a file input button design (it is the second button that says UPLOAD) how would I accomplish this design in HTML using CSS and or Javascript???

[image: IMGUR image]

Comment: I have reworded the question

Comment: You should offer what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok try this out:

html:

```
<p class="form">
    <input type="text" id="path" />
    <label class="uploadFile">upload<span><input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" /></span>
</label>
</p>
```

css:

```
.form input[type="file"]{
    z-index: 999;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0);-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=0)";
    cursor: pointer;
    _cursor: hand;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    left:0;
}

.uploadFile{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#fff;
    display:block;
    width:197px;
    height:31px;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:30px;
    float:left;
    color:#000;
    border:solid 1px #000;
}
input[type="text"]{
border: none;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
width: 200px;
}
```

js:

```
$('#myfile').change(function(){
        $('#path').val($(this).val());
    });

$(function(){
    if($("#path").val() == ""){
        $("#path").val("No file choosen");
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sQYZ2/7/)